# How many test cases would I need to test all branches?

Tags: python, testing, code-coverage

The test method is the following:

```
def testArrayLength(array):# array passed through
  length = len(array);  # get number of chars in the container
  if(length > 20):
    return 1
  if(length > 1):
    return 0
  if(length == 0):
     return -1
```

Would there be a minimum of three test cases to have 100% branch coverage?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: A minimum of ONE test case is enough, using pytest and mark.parametrize:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html
You would just supply input data and assertion expected result

Comment: Python does not have pre-variable type declarations, nor does it use `//` as its comment character. You are also missing several `:`; please provide syntactically valid Python code in your question.

Comment: If you want to type hint the syntax is `name: type`, so `length: int`, not the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

You would probably want to have a test case for every possible outcome of your function. In your case, your possible outcomes are 1, 0, and -1.

So yes, you need 3 test cases for 100% coverage of this function.

EDIT: As @chepner points out, None is also a possible test case, giving four possible outcomes.

Comment: That's definitely not right imho.

Comment: @Gameplay Not helpful, explain why. Also, if this is a problem with semantics, then go away.

Comment: Just read my comment directly below author's question mate :) The author didn't specify the framework to be used, so I didn't post my thoughts as an answer, but what you said just ain't right. Also granularity of the tests depends on specific use case and internal rules.

Comment: @Gameplay A "test case" generally includes the input data and the corresponding expected results. So running one test **function** with different inputs doesn't mean there's only one **test case**.

Comment: @iBug point taken, my bad (confused terms, probably I'm tired), sorry Charles

Comment: `None` is also a possible outcome, depending on the value of `array`. (Don't assume it's a list. string, etc; it could be anything that defines a `__len__` method, which could return a negative value.)